# Match key ib Hashmap using arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

Hi  I have an array list which contain some date

ArrayList dates = new ArrayList();

I have list of date something like :

```
All dates between:2015-10-29
All dates between:2015-10-30
All dates between:2015-10-31
All dates between:2015-11-01
All dates between:2015-11-02
All dates between:2015-11-03
```

And I have a Hashmap  somethin like

```
HashMap<String,String> segCount=userSegmentDAO.getDateWiseCount(user.getOrgId(), startDate, end_Date,fromDate,endDate);
```

where I am getting value some thing like

```
2015-10-29   6
2015-10-31   3
2015-11-02   5
```

No what I want here I  am traversing array list till last and want to compare with hashmap  if hash map conatian that date as a key then leave it as it is otherwise put that date as a key  in hashmap and placed 0 for value.

Comment: is `containsKey()` not working ?

Comment: Why is your map mapping from String not from Date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (String each: dates ){
            if(!segCount.containsKey(each)){
                segCount.put(each, "0");
            }
        }
```

However, it is better to use Date instead of String as Map key and array element.

Answer (score 0):

Or if you use java8

```
dates.stream()
            .filter(dateString -> !segCount.containsKey(dateString))
            .forEach(dateString -> segCount.put(dateString, "0"));
```

Answer (score 0):

In Java 8 you can do

```
for (String s : dates)
    segCount.putIfAbsent(s, "0");
```